How to Determine Condensate Line Exit
I live in a townhome that is 4 floors. I have a A/C unit on the 4th floor that cools the 4th and 3rd floor. The condensate drain pipe is clogged, but I can't find where the condensate drain pipe "exits" the house. Is there a way to figure that out?

Is this a window unit, or what?

it should be outside (obviously), and it looks like PVC pipe (about 1/2 inch) and about 1 foot from the ground.
To unclog, use some bleach (to kill the mildew) and then pore a gallon of water while have someone outside observing where it comes out –
